# Angular change query params order after #

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when I call my website like

```
www.mysite.com/#!/mypath/mypath2/mypath3?queryParam1=123&queryParam2=123123
```

angular changes the query params order like this

```
www.mysite.com/#!/mypath/mypath2/mypath3?queryParam2=123123queryParam1=123
```

Why angular changes the order and how can I handle this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify parameter order with Angular's $http service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130981/is-it-possible-to-specify-parameter-order-with-angulars-http-service)